# How to add google recaptcha not working on joomla 3.7?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have problem with google recaptcha on my joomla site. I am using gk contact form plugin and joomla 3.7.0 version. But recaptcha is not showing due to console errors.

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Recaptcha is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):402)
at i (jquery.min.js?78f5c4952e9cfe6f41e9ad437e81ec9d:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?78f5c4952e9cfe6f41e9ad437e81ec9d:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js?78f5c4952e9cfe6f41e9ad437e81ec9d:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js?78f5c4952e9cfe6f41e9ad437e81ec9d:2)
```

any solution?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.

Comment: What if you try with using a working url for google recaptcha:  https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js You can always check these here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display